# Vuejs display a value within an object returned by a method

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I want to display the 'name' value only, within the object returned from the method.

- What is currently displayed is: [ { "city": "Ottawa", "name": "Senators", "province": "Ontario", ".key": "-Kp00XARET2EDFRZVMks" } ]
- I want displayed is "Senators".

Here's snippets of my code:

```
... in the template    
<td>{{props.item.away}} {{ teamDetail(props.item.away) }}</td>

... in the script
methods: {
        teamDetail(inpt) {
            return this.teams.filter((team) => {
                return team['.key'] ==  inpt;
            })
        },
```

props.item.away is the .key sent to teamDetail to retrieve the object for a specific team, the object returned in this case is [ { "city": "Ottawa", "name": "Senators", "province": "Ontario", ".key": "-Kp00XARET2EDFRZVMks" } ]

to display the 'name' only, I tried within the template {{ teamDetail(props.item.away).name }}  and within the filter in the method

I also tried with computed but I can't access the key with 'this.props.item.away'

```
computed: {
        teamDtl() {
            return this.teams.filter((team) => {
                return team['.key'] ==  this.props.item.away;
            })
        },
```

Comment: The object is wrapped in an array. Do `{{ teamDetail(props.item.away)[0].name }}`

Comment: {{ teamDetail(props.item.home)[0] }} does isolate the object,however {{ teamDetail(props.item.home)[0].name }} generates the following error:  Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: You need to check for undefined, then. Probably getting complicated enough that you should make a computed for it, rather than trying to put the expression in your template.

Comment: makes sense, although I haven't been successful with it so far...

Comment: I'll need a method since I need to pass in the argument (key), this is generating a schedule within a table for multiple games.  I want to return the object to the UI so I could display various values of the object.  So my current method should work, with some fixings (?)

Comment: SOLVED, thanks Roy for your help!  Updated the method and now it works with {{ teamDetail(props.item.away)[0].name }}  but I'm still not sure I know where the error was.  I typed out teamDetail: function (inpt) instead of teamDetail (inpt) and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked -  {{ teamDetail(props.item.away)[0].name }}

The error was in the data returned from the database.